# Comparing sub List boolean items for MCDC combinations - Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Python - Comparing sub List boolean items for MCDC combinations

I have generated truth table for expresion a&b, below list contains all combinations for 2 inputs i.e., 1st and 2nd item in sublist is input and 3rd item is output of the 1st two inputs.

`Mylist [[True, True, True],[True, False, False],[False, True, True],[False, False, False]]`

1. I have to compare 1st element of 1st sublist with 1st element of 2nd sublist and remaining elements should remains same.
2. last element of sublist is output of remain elements of that sublist,
3. if 1st element of 1st and 2nd sublist are NOT same and the last elements(output) are not same then return these two sublists.(output is changed because of change in single input value without changing others)

Example:

expression: (A|B)&C , D is output of the (A|B)&C this is the last item in each sublist.

```
A     B     C     D
```

`0 [True, True, True, True]`
`1 [True, True, False, False]`
`2 [True, False, True, True]`
`3 [True, False, False, False]`
`4 [False, True, True, True]`
`5 [False, True, False, False]`
`6 [False, False, True, False]`
`7 [False, False, False, False]`

expecting outputs: for N- inputs N+1 outputs (It can be any N+1 combinations in 2^N sets)

`2 [True, False, True, True]`
`3 [True, False, False, False]`
`4 [False, True, True, True]`
`6 [False, False, True, False]`

Thanks in advance.